# "tadinho dele (/ta.'di.ɲo/). " Tadinho??? De onde és que falas diferente de mim?"

Tags: pronúncia, fonemas, fonologia, diferenças-regionais

Em todo o estado do Rio de Janeiro a letra **"d"**, quando seguida de "i", é pronunciada como **/dʒ/** por cem por cento da população.  No entanto, observo com relativa frequência a pronúncia **/d/** em não-nativos do estado. Como por exemplo nas seguintes palavras: escondido, diagrama, diário, assim como nos exemplos que cito a seguir.

Há alguns dias, conversando com uma turista proveniente de Campina Grande, Paraíba, chamou-me a atenção a sua pronúncia das palavras **"tadinho" (/ta.'di.ɲo/) e "todinho" (/to.'di.ɲo/)** e.g. "Tadinho, ele se molhou todinho!', ditas com forte sotaque nordestino.

Ouvindo músicas, também reparei em uma banda do exército do estado de São Paulo pronunciando **/d/** em **1'01"** e em **2'99"** da [**Canção do Soldado**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_MmgdDnOLQ) ("se a pátria amada for um **dia** ultrajada, lutaremos com valor") Chama a atenção também a pronúncia tipicamente paulista de "to**rr**ão" em **1'19"** como se fora um só "r").

Em Portugal, em minhas incursões turísticas, percebi apenas a forma /d/ mas não tão marcante quanto a que ouvi da jovem paraibana ao dizer "todinho molhado".

Minha pergunta então é a seguinte: alguém é capaz de fornecer um mapa escrito, mesmo que impreciso, de em que locais a letra "d", seguida de "i", é pronunciada /d/ e /dʒ/ no Brasil e em Portugal?

Comment: Muito interessante, não fazia ideia que também pronunciavam o «d» como os portugas ;) Em Portugal acho que toda a gente pronuncia como /d/, mas sem certeza.

Comment: Dentro do Estado de São Paulo em cidades vizinhas vai encontrar diferenças de pronúncias do d.

Comment: Gente, sotaque carioca é só no Rio mesmo, ué. (Também o t seguido de e em posição final). GenTE, ardentE, falantE. etc. :) Me parece incrível que ninguém soltou a palavra carioca.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, no caso da canção me parece que é hipercorreção; não creio que as mesmas pessoas que estão cantando falem dessa forma no cotidiano. É uma canção formal, provavelmente numa ocasião formal, e os cantores estão "caprichando". Como se escreve "dia", estão pronunciando /dia/. E não é consistente; em 0:33 se pode ouvir "altiva" com a palatalização bem clara, /altʃiva/.

Ao que eu saiba, a pronúncia corrente em São Paulo é palatalizada, como aliás na maior parte do território. Ao que eu saiba só há duas exceções: no litoral do nordeste, onde o "i" reduzido, em vez do mais comum /j/, se pronuncia /ɨ/ (e aí o "d" é pronunciado, me parece, mais como /ð/ do que como /d/), e no Oeste do Rio Grande do Sul, Santa Catarina e Paraná, onde o "e" final não é reduzido, mas pronunciado /e/.

Quanto aos erres, não creio que em São Paulo se pronuncie "torrão" como se tivesse um erre só. Aliás não encontro a palavra na canção. Em 1:19 o que ouço é "sublime saber amar". Encontro sim "terra", logo antes de "altiva", e a pronúncia do "rr" é exatamente a que se espera, /ʁ/. O fenômeno que descreves só ocorre, ao que eu tenha conhecimento, com "r" pós-vocálico, que, de São Paulo para o sul (e para o noroeste, se estendendo talvez até a Amazônia?) se pronuncia /r/ ou /ɹ/ em vez da pronúncia corrente no Rio de Janeiro, /ʁ/.

Comment: Luís,  Não, em 1 minuto e 19 segundos, ouve-se "com a alma adorar, o torrão onde se nasce".  Isso é típico de Paulistas do interior, descendentes de italianos.  Não sou nenhum "expert" no assunto mas há muito tempo li uma tese sobre a influência da imigração italiana no falar de São Paulo. Essa pronúncia era citada e tinha como exemplo a pronuncia de "carroça" como se tivesse um só "r".

Comment: Quanto a "altiva", já é "t + i".  Eu justamente não inclui esse fonema na pergunta para não complicar as coisas, mas já ouvi algumas pessoas de outros estados pronunciarem "tia" diferente da maioria dos brasileiros, sem o "tch".

Comment: Existem várias gravações da Canção do Soldado no youtube.  A que me refiro em 1'19" é a do link que deixei na pergunta.

Comment: Luís, será que estamos a falar da mesma música?  Não há a palavra "altiva" na gravação da Canção do Soldado cujo link está la na pergunta.

Comment: Luís, observe a pronuncia dos integrantes da Banda de Pau e Corda (Recife - PE).  Em [**Frevo nº 1 do Recife**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0HztRAlCig) observe a pronuncia de "saudade" em 0'06", "dia" em 1'12", "antiga" em 1'50".   Em [**Aquela Rosa**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC45AJrzl_g) a pronuncia de "cultivo" e "partiu".   E não é hipercorreção.  Há uma região do Nordeste onde realmente se fala assim.

Comment: @Centaurus - No Nordeste com certeza não é hipercorreção. É pronunciado /di/ (ou talvez mais precisamente /ðɨ/) mesmo. Mas o teu exemplo é de uma banda de São Paulo; em São Paulo - e não no Nordeste - penso que pode ser hipercorreção.

Comment: Quanto à letra da Canção do Soldado, segui o teu linque, e conferi com a letra deste site, https://www.letras.mus.br/exercito-brasileiro/409775/ . O trecho a que te referes diz "com a alma adorar a terra onde se nasce", tanto no teu linque quanto no meu. E a pronúncia no teu linque é /ʁ/. A pronúncia italianada a que te referes é mais comum no Rio Grande do Sul rural, onde os imigrantes italianos permaneceram na área rural, sem remigrar para a indústria como em SP. Mas em qualquer lugar, RS ou SP, creio que tal pronúncia seria barrada num coral do Exército.

Comment: Mas tens razão, no teu linque eles cantam "torrão" em vez de terra. Porém eu ouço o /rr/ dobrado como deve ser, "torrão" e não "torão".

Comment: Continuei a discussão no Falatório, conforme me foi sugerido. Lá está minha resposta aos teus comentários.

Comment: Em algumas cidades do interior paulista, como São Carlos e Araraquara, a pronúncia do /d/ antes de /i/ também é bem comum.

Comment: Num falar mais rural no estado de SP pode-se ouvir pessoas falando o R bem mais puxado que o normal. O problema é escrever a diferença da pronúncia. Partindo da pronúncia de Barão, por exemplo, a ponta da língua treme perto dos dentes; o torrão com r de barão só que com a língua puxada pro fundo da boca, suponho dê uma ideia da pronúncia que se quer chegar aqui (o que simularia o arrasto dos dois erres). Ou pode assistir as novelas da globo com moradores de áreas rurais.

Comment: @AndréLyra   Eu vejo três formas de se pronunciar o r.  A primeira é fácil de explicar, é o r de "caro", "fera".   O segundo, é como eu pronuncio "torrão", onde vibram os pilares anteriores e as amígdalas, e parece que vou escarrar.  A terceira, é a forma como pronunciam "torrão" na música em que a vibração não é nos pilares e nem nas amígdalas, mas sim no final do palato duro e no palato mole.

Comment: @AndréLyra  E a língua também vibra

Answer (score 1):

quanto ao mapa solicitado: na maior parte do nordeste brasileiro e na região sul as pessoas falam desta forma. No restante do Brasil o comum é falar da mesma forma que no Rio/São Paulo...É uma questão mais de sotaque..